# Does bitcoind re-index or reverify downloaded blocks upon startup?

Tags: reindex

If so is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It walks back a small number of blocks and re-verifies them, this ensures there's no obvious corruption and warms the cache. It takes a few tens of seconds at maximum on most hardware. You can adjust or effectively disable this using `checklevel=1`, but it is generally inadvisable to do so.